# Application for getting the pixel area of an area in a image

Tags: windows, web-apps

Looking for an application that can get the pixel area of the highlighted region in an area.

The measurement needed to be pixels so that I can compare the algorithm we use to get its accuracy.

It can be a web app or a windows application.

[image: Example]

Comment: When you say you want to get the AREA, are you talking about the total Qty of pixels?